# C++: how do I convert a string into a float where the starting char can change?

Tags: c++

I have this kinda of input:

```
x4.9
x.25
C400
```

What is the best way to drop the first char and convert to float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sscanf(), eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float f; 
char *str = "x4.9"; 

if( sscanf(str, "%*c%f", &f) == 1 )
{
    // use f as needed ...
}
```

Comment: Why was this voted down?  It is a perfectly valid solution to the problem.

Comment: It's not very C++-like, which is likely why it was downvoted.  Still, I'm not real impressed by streams, and often find the C equivalents handier, if not as safe.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

...
char c;
float f; 
std::cin >> c >> f;
```

`std::cin >> c` reads one character from standard input and stores the character in `c`, and `std::cin >> f` reads and stores one float from standard input.  `std::cin >> c >> f` is equivalent to `std::cin >> c; std::cin >> f;`

You can loop something like the above to read a series of inputs.  `cin` skips over whitespace by default, so the newlines won't be an issue.

Comment: This would get my vote if it would also show that _input must_ __always__ _be checked_.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is line-oriented, so you might want to read lines first, and then process these:

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!
void process_line(std::istream& is);

void read_input(std::istream& is)
{
  while(is.good()) {
    std::string line;
    //is >> std::ws;            // might want to allow leading whitespace
    std::getline(is,line);
    if(is && !line.empty()) {
      std::istringstream iss(line); 
      process_line(iss);
      if(!iss.eof())            // reading number failed
        break;
    }
  }
  if(!is.eof()) // reading failed before eof
    throw("input error, read_input() blew it!");
}

void process_line(std::istream& is)
{
  char ch;
  double d;
  is >> ch >> d/* >> std::ws*/; // trailing whitespace usually often is acceptable
  if(!is.eof())                 // should be at the end of line
    return;
  process_number(ch,d);         // I don't know whether ch is important
}
```

Error handling could be improved, but this should give you a start.